# How to "relax" the equation of a circle to get a better-looking circle?

Tags: java

I need to write a program using java for an assignment.
The program needs to output a circle of a given radius at a given coordinate.
So far I've created a for loop nested inside of another for loop, to scan all coordinates and print a "#" whenever the coordinate satisfies the equation of a circle, which is: (x−a)^2 +(y−b)^2 =r^2

However, my circle comes out missing certain coordinates.

I believe it is because I didn't take into account one of the hints included in the question.

The hint is:
The discrete world we have to work with makes it hard to express the strict equality in equation 1 (equation 1 being the equation of a circle). Can you relax that equality in order to draw better circles?

I would greatly appreciate if someone would give me any ideas as to how to "relax" the equation of a circle to output a fuller circle.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `"Can you relax that equality in order to draw better circles?"` -- weed used to work for me.

Comment: Please provide some [code](http://sscce.org/) showing the issue, and maybe a screenshot too :)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm (and follow links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that integer arithmetic's rounding is impacting your results.

Integer rounding isn't really rounding, it's truncating (all decimal parts are lost ie (int).9 = 0), so you could first try adding .5 to each result (or -.5 if the number is negative) before letting the truncating occur.

If that doesn't help, try drawing multiple circles on the same grid by repeating the process but with r +/- .5, to "fill in" the jagged gaps.

If that's not enough, I would "draw" a circle on a virtual grid at a larger scale (maybe 4x) and with a thicker line (draw 3 circles of r +/- 1), then shrink it to fit the real grid.

Comment: Thanks, I added 0.5 which helped a lot, but do you have any idea why the bottom left corner is empty? I have a screenshot of it in my answer to this post.

Comment: It's not printing where both i and j are negative because sqrt can not be negative and you are comparing i and j to a sqrt. Better to test that `i*i == <parameter to sqrt>`

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when I cast the coordinates to int, and also add 0.5, it looks a lot better, but I'm not sure why the left side is left out.

[image]

It doesn't need to be so nice, the "goal" is this:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, that looks a bit better. But there is still curiously no "#"s for quadrant 4 .. and some missing in 1. How are negative numbers handled? (And shouldn't sometimes -0.5 be added vs 0.5 if taking Bohemian's suggestion?)

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not sure, but I think i and j should never be negative since i goes from posX-radius (14-5=9) to posX+radius (14+5=19) and j goes from posY+radius (8+5=13) to posY-radius (8-5=3)

Comment: @user2864740 Do you have any idea why the fourth quadrant is empty?